# Change text alignment when a div resizes using css in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I used flex containers and div(s) within it  to make a menu bar for my site. All the text has been aligned to the center.

I need the text to be aligned to left once it resizes in smaller devices. Is there a way to do it using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If based on screen size, then you can use CSS `@media screen` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media in stylesheet or `<style>...</style>` tags.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  p,li{
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Meaning that at a max width of `767px` to execute the enclosed styles.

NB: you will have to look out for CSS Specificity. To ensure styles in other sections don't still override the ones in the `@media` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity